# Backbone.history.start() giving out error

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Anonymous function error is pointing to

```
Backbone.history.start()
```

Below is my index.html and main.js.

I have a feeling, the jquery,underscore and backbone files may not be loading properly,due to which this error is happening
Kind of beginner in backbone.Any help is greatly appreciated

versions used:

```
underscore - 1.8.3
backbone - 1.1.2
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var Theater = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates:{},
        Routers:{}
    }

    Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});


    Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Theater.Models.Movie,
        url: "/json",
        initialize: function(){
            console.log("Movies initialize")
        }
    });


    Theater.Routers = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize:function(){  console.log("defaultRoute");},
        routes: {
            "": "defaultRoute" 
        },
        defaultRoute: function () {
            console.log("defaultRoute");
        }
    });

    console.log("gonna call approuter");
    var appRouter = new Theater.Routers();
    Backbone.history.start();

   });
```

Comment: you should click the line it's referring to in console. It might offer a bit more information as to the exact line (if applicable)

Comment: @Seth : yea, i did that and that's how i got to understand Backbone.history.start() is having some problem :)

Comment: So the line it's referring to is `Backbone.history.start()`? You should try putting a breakpoint on it and stepping through all the functions calls to see where it's breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're probably using a pretty old version of jQuery, 1.6 maybe?

1.6 doesn't include the `on` method for listening to events, so I'd guess that when you call `Backbone.history.start()`, Backbone throws an error when it tries to do:

```
Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
```

Upgrade your version of jQuery. If you need to support IE 6/7/8 upgrade to jQuery 1.x, if not upgrade to 2.x.